# remove products from mysql if 1 column is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

Well this is a bit difficult to ask but I will try my best to ask it in a way that everyone understands it. (well i hope). :)

I have a table in mysql called "products". 
There is a column in that table called "clicks".

how can i remove/delete a product from the mysql database IF the "clicks" column is Empty or 0 ?

all the products get saved in the mysql database with a unique ID by the way.

any help or code samples would be appreciated so I understad it better.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `DELETE FROM table WHERE clicks IS NULL OR clicks = 0;`

Comment: awesome. Thanks ever so much. that is what I needed. simple. easy and understndable.